# NameError: name 'order_vals' is not defined. - Python, Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Alright I know this question title looks EXTREMELY familiar to many on this site but I swear I reviewed quite a few and almost all were issues with indentation and variable scope.  That does not appear to be the case here so I'm hoping someone can help out.

So I'm writing a function in my `models.py` to parse out a dataframe into a list of objects to send to my `views.py` function and I get the NameError referenced in the title, despite declaring the offending variable **immediately** before it is used.  The code is shown below

```
# Setting some default values for our order records.
    order_vals = {
        'site': 'WH30-123',
        'sale_type': 'CUST',
        'sales_rep': 'JOHN DOE',
        'customer_number': "123456789",
        'cust_po_number': '{}-{}'.format(self.start_date.strftime(d_form),self.end_date.strftime(d_form)),
        'fob': 'ORIGIN'
    }
    # Using a helper function to generate a list of orders.
    orders=helpers.order_parse(ords,order_vals)
```

Okay, not only can I see nothing wrong with typing up a little dictionary and passing it to a function, when I step through this code using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` I can execute `order_vals` and it returns all the values exactly as I've written them out.  I'm at a total loss here.  If it helps, here is the function I am passing the dictionary to.

```
def order_parse(shipments, order_values):
  # Creating our empty list
  orders=list()
  # Iterating over each
  for i,row in shipments.iterrows():
    orders.append(
        dict(
            order_vals,**{
                'shipto_number': row['shipto_number'],
                'order_number': row['order_number']
                }
            )
        )
  return orders
```

I've also already tried using the kwargs specifications to no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Python, but the variable is named "order_values" in your function (see params) and you are still using the old name "order_vals" in it which does not exist in the context of your function...?

Comment: Yeah this was just me using one convention in the Jupyter Notebook where I was developing the process and a slightly different one in the helpers.py file in my Django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the line numbers in the traceback. The problem actually looks like it's in the function you're passing the dictionary to:

```
def order_parse(shipments, order_values):               # <--- "order_values"
  # Creating our empty list
  orders=list()
  # Iterating over each
  for i,row in shipments.iterrows():
    orders.append(
        dict(
            order_vals,**{                              # <--- "order_vals"
                'shipto_number': row['shipto_number'],
                'order_number': row['order_number']
                }
            )
        )
  return orders
```

Comment: Holy Crap.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The order_vals is not defined inside your function.The local variable for the passed order_vals inside the function is order_values as per your function definition.
Try:

```
        def order_parse(shipments, order_values):
               # Creating our empty list
               orders=list()
               # Iterating over each
               for i,row in shipments.iterrows():
               orders.append(
                           dict(
                           order_values,**{
                             'shipto_number': row['shipto_number'],
            'order_number': row['order_number']
                           }
                           )
                )
```

return orders